# Mysql - how to limit the number of transcations per second on a table

Tags: mysql

How to limit the number of transcations per second on a table in Mysql?

Like to prevent brute force login via an API

Comment: I suspect the API should limit this, not the database.

Comment: @David I know, but I'm looking for options

Answer (score 1):

As David says, do this on the API. You cannot and **should not** limit your database. There's no way to distinguish the origin of the query, so you'll just shut down the database for everyone if one person decides to flood it, making a denial-of-service attack easier.

As for a solution there are many examples.

Nginx has a rate-limiting feature built in that can limit requests per interval of time, and is very flexible. This can be focused on particular endpoints, paths, or other criteria, making it easy to protect whatever parts of your system are vulnerable.

You'll also need to block clients that are trying to attack your system. Consider something like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which can read logs and automatically block source traffic from offenders. Log every failed attempt and this tool can do the rest.